# How to get actual ViewModel variable value from MainActivity in FragmentActivity in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

The variable is being changed in MainActivity(FragmentActivity is the current fragment that is shown there). When a user is pressing the button FragmentActivity gets value from SharedData class and if it's true then make a Toast.
But after successful Toast in MainActivity, the value doesn't change in FragmentActivity. What is incorrect in my code?

```html
MainActivity:
private lateinit var viewModel: SharedData
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_fragment_switcher)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedData::class.java)
    viewModel.currentFragmentStatus.value = false
}
fun addMe(el: InfoClass) {
    if(!viewModel.currentFragmentStatus.value!!){
        mainHandler.post {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "The app is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            viewModel.allowed = true
            viewModel.currentFragmentStatus.value = true
        }
    }
}

FragmentActivity:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedData::class.java)
    viewModel.currentFragmentStatus.observe(this, Observer{
        allowed = it
    })
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
if (allowed) {
    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "You are great!",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
    ).show()
    viewModel.fragmentStatus = true
}

SharedData:
class SharedData: ViewModel() {
    var allowed: Boolean = false
    var fragmentStatus: Boolean = false
    val currentFragmentStatus: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` is only called once (in a lifecycle). It won't be called again after the state changes in the `ViewModel`.

If you want to show the `Toast` when the state changes, do it inside of the state observer